# Issue Launching Simplicity Studio

Tags: eclipse, simplicity-studio

Just recently downloaded Simplicity Studio, and I'm having issues launching the application. Here's the log file information:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbEa5.png)

I've tried adding the -data parameter to following to the startup file and still not able to run the program. Any help would be appreciated:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui7aB.png)